# Add a toolstripcontrolhost to a customcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip

I am working on a Project where I need a very specific type of ToolStrip. Overloading the ToolStrip itself is an option but it is NOT my preferred option as I wish to use a custom Designer and can't inherit the ToolStripDesigner as its set Internal. I can work around this but I find this sort of stuff messy.

So my preferred option is to develop my own ToolStrip with my own Designer but I don't wish to start from scratch so what I wish to do is host ToolStripControlHosts within my own Custom Control. There is a lot of information on doing the other way around but these are of course no help.

How do I host ToolStripControlHosts in a custom Control?

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Creating a `ToolStrip` from scratch is a long hard journey to go. I recommend to start by deriving from `ToolStrip` and if you need a new designer, just create the designer from scratch. Then register the designer for your `ToolStrip`. `[Designer(typeof(YourToolStripDesigner))]`

Comment: About your question *How do I host ToolStripControlHosts in a custom Control?* `ToolStripControlHost` is a component. It's not a control. So while you can have them in components collection of your control or in any other collection property, but you should handle the appearance yourself.

Comment: Reza I agree. This is what I think I'll be doing, been fiddling about the other way to much and got to focused on that solution. Thanks. By the way I didn't say the ToolStripControlHost was a Control, it hosts Controls.

Comment: OK, it's good that you know :) I just wanted to absorb your attention to the point that they are components and they don't have any appearance by default and you should provide the appearance yourself (using the hosted control of the `ToolStripControlHost`).

Comment: By the way, can you share more about the requirement? What are the requirements that move you toward creating a new designer for `ToolStrip`?

Comment: I wish to replace the Forms title bar with a much more powerful control. One that allows people to add other buttons, textboxes etc at both design and runtime, as well as a menu strip that only shows up when the user mouses over it, replacing the Title as well as other stuff.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei. I've been working on this all night and have had to violate so many best practices and programming rules I've developed myself that I'm going to find another way. Thanks for the though.

Comment: Hope you find a good solution :)